# i want data between time 10:AM to 10:PM on per day in influxdb

Tags: database, influxdb

i want data between time 10:AM to 10:PM on per day in influxdb

if I am used Regular-Expression to ignore date then I getting timestamp error same 
can anyone help 
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your code/query that is producing the "timestamp error"?

Comment: select count(volume) from ACC where time >'0000-00-00T10:00:00.0000Z' and time <'0000-00-00T17:00:00.0000Z' group by time(1d)                                 
ERR: invalid timestamp string

Comment: OK... well those aren't real timestamps so that explains the error. Unfortunately I think what you're trying to do (get data only in a certain range for each day) isn't possible yet. See this [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6723). Luckily you want data in a 12 hour range, however, so you could just `group by time(12h)`, make sure the offsets line up to 10am/pm, and just process every 2nd result in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative time range, group by day.

If you want only specific times for each day, you will need to calculate the date range client side and specify an explicit date and time range for each daily query.

Relative range with specific time is not supported.

Relative for past 7 days:

```
SELECT count(volume) from ACC 
WHERE time > now() - 7d
GROUP BY time(1d)
```

Explicit for 10am to 10am for one day:

```
SELECT count(volume) from ACC 
WHERE time >= '2018-01-07T10:00:00'
AND time < '2018-01-08T10:00:00'
GROUP BY time(1d)
```

Comment: thanks for giving me your valuable time but I already solved this problem with client-side function